# Debug assertion failed . while using fscanf

Tags: c, debugging, scanf, assertion

Hey I've tried a lot of programs in Visual Studio and in most of them when i try taking the input from a stream ( while using `fscanf` ) it invariably throws a `debug assertion failed error ..`

and goes on to say:

`stream != NULL`. Since I have gotten this error a number of times .. I assume there is a flaw in the way I'm using `fscanf`. I would appreciate it if someone could tell me the usage or .. give me a demo sample code that illustrates the simple usage .. !

I tried looking up the error .. in most places it said I haven't closed the file .. but I have and I'm a little confused .. I appreciate any help .. thanks a lot :)

```
    printf("Enter No of states\n");
     Q=5;
  //  scanf("%d",&Q);

   // READING ZERO MATRIX
  // reading the matrix from f0.sta
 {
  FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("c:\\tc\\fuzzy\\f0.sta","r");
   for(i=1;i<=Q;i++)
    for(j=1;j<=Q;j++)
     fscanf(fp,"%f",&a0[i][j]);

    fclose(fp);
 }
 // READING ONE MATRIX
 // reading the matrix from f0.sta
   FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("c:\\tc\\fuzzy\\f1.sta","r");
     for(i=1;i<=Q;i++)
      for(j=1;j<=Q;j++)
        fscanf(fp,"%f",&a1[i][j]);

    fclose(fp);
```

This is the code bit.

Comment: Can you put your code here, to let us see how did you try to use the given function? There is no point of describing how you should use fscanf, that's what the documentations are for. You could just read a documentation or you could paste a code example to let us see what you have tried, maybe we can give you a simple solution.

Comment: @LajosArpad     

hey i have put up the part of the program that uses the fscanf function .. sorry i didn't put it up earlier .. !

Comment: In what line does the error occur?

Comment: it says the error occurs in a totally different file that holds the definitions of fscanf !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `fp` is NULL. The most likely reason is that one of the files (or both) do not exist, or can't be opened (for example, because some other process is using it).

I would start by adding some error checking after the two `fopen()` calls: compare the result to `NULL` and if it is `NULL`, examine `errno`.

Comment: u are god ... :) thank you so much ... the comparison to null helped ! i now realised how stupid i am :)

Comment: @abhishekb, after programming for so many years, I still forgot to check for NULL and ended up here.  Thanks NPE. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your loop counters start at 1 instead of 0, which is odd for C programming.  What's likely happening is you're not allocating enough space in the array, i.e. you have

```
double a[5][5];
```

when you need

```
double a[6][6];
```

so you're stepping on something past the end of the array.  Better to have your loop be

```
for(i=0;i<Q;i++)
  for(j=0;j<Q;j++)
```

so you don't waste the 0 slots in the array.